# Kendo Grid - How to conditionally apply a min value validator to a field?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, conditional-statements, min, kendo-validator

In my editable grid I have a field, one of which I want to have a minimum value of 0 or 1 depending on which row it is.  For instance:

```
ID: {editable: false},
NameField: { editable: false },
Count: { 
    editable: true, 
    type: "number",   
    validation: {
        required: true, 
        min:{ if( NameField === "George" {1} else {0} },
        step: 1, 
       validationMessage: "My validation message"
    }
 },
```

How do I refer in `min` to the *current* `NameField` value?

Comment: I reckon it will be easiest to achieve this in the edit event of the grid as opposed to in the column/field definitions. In the edit event you can examine the properties of the model and check the value of the name field which you can then use to set the min value.

Comment: What kind of `editing` do you use in the grid (popup or inline)?